# make time function with Interpolation of discrete time data and use this function in Solve and Plot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, interpolation

I have value of a and b in terms of time for discrete value of time. How can i make a time function with interpolation? after that and generate a[t_]:=Interpolation of some point in terms of time... and b[t_]:=... i need to put x[t] and y[t] from solve to them that if i type x[6.5] and press shift+enter i can give correct value of x[t] in t=6.5s . after determine x[t] and y[t] i want to plot them in function of time. My input is a(t=1):2, a(t=2):4,...b(t=1):7,b(t=2):5,... and my favorite out put is x[t],y[t] when time is in interval of (t=1,t=10)
my sample code that didn't work is:

```
ClearAll[a, b, x, y]
a[t_] := Interpolation[{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 7}, {5, 6}, {6, 5}, {7, 3}, {8, 2}, {9, 1}, {10, 0.5}];
b[t_] := Interpolation[{1, 7}, {2, 5}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 3}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}, {8, 5}, {9, 3}, {10, 1}];
Solve[a[t]* x[t] + y[t] == 7 && b[t]* x[t] - y[t] == 1, {x[t], y[t]}]
a[6.5]
x[6.5]
Plot[x[t], y[t], {t, 1, 10}]
```

All of my data is between t=1s and t=10s and i need x[t],y[t] and plot of them in this interval of time.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate and solve this function equation with NDSolve.

Use spline interpolation, because it can be differentiated.

```
ClearAll[a, b, x, y]
ptsa = {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 7}, {5, 6}, {6, 5}, {7, 3}, {8, 
2}, {9, 1}, {10, 0.5}};
a = Interpolation[ptsa, InterpolationOrder -> 3, Method -> "Spline"];
ptsb = {{1, 7}, {2, 5}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {5, 3}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}, {8, 
5}, {9, 3}, {10, 1}};
b = Interpolation[ptsb, InterpolationOrder -> 3, Method -> "Spline"];

Plot[a[t], {t, 1, 10}, Epilog -> Point@ptsa]

Plot[b[t], {t, 1, 10}, Epilog -> Point@ptsb]
```

Not shown here.

Find starting values.

```
sol = Solve[
  a[1]*x[1] + y[1] == 7 && b[1]*x[1] - y[1] == 1, {x[1], y[1]}]

(*   {{x[1] -> 0.888889, y[1] -> 5.22222}}   *)

ndsol = NDSolve[
  D[a[t]*x[t] + y[t] == 7 && b[t]*x[t] - y[t] == 1, t] && 
  x[1] == (x[1] /. sol) && y[1] == (y[1] /. sol), {x, y}, {t, 1, 10}]

Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. ndsol], {t, 1, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

Proof the result

```
Plot[Evaluate[{a[t]*x[t] + y[t], b[t]*x[t] - y[t]} /. ndsol], {t, 1, 
   10}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you dear Akku14. very good answer.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I want to know can i receive ptsa and ptsb from an excel file? if my data have a lot of interpolation point it is not simple that i enter all of my point in this way. How can i receive ptsa and ptsb from an excel file? and if i want too use D[a[t],{t,2}] this code give to me a curve with a lot of break point. when i increase interpolation order this problem is solved, is this right way for have a function without break point in second order of derivative?
Please help me for calling ptsa and ptsb from an excel file. thank you very much my friend.

Comment: I am not an expert in importing data, but search for "data from excel file" here in Mathematica Stack Exchange, and you will get a lot of help. You are right, if you want second derivative, you have to increase interpolation order. But always have a look whether the interpolation curve seems reasonable and has no artificial bumps. Higher derivatives are only close to reality, if you have a lot of data points.